# Name of Rake task in ps output?

Tags: bash, ruby, ps

```
pid = `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep rake | awk '{print $2}'`
```

This is a bunch of ruby code that executes piped linux commands.  While I usually just use `ps aux`, just because, I noticed that the `rake` task it finds outputs the path like so:

```
deployer 10149   1  0 Apr11 ?    00:01:08 /home/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake
```

If this rake task was ran from inside a bash script with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake qc:work &
```

Is there a way to find `qc:work` or some kind of identifier, just in case i run more than one rake task in the future?  Maybe ps isn't what is needed, since I run with the `&`... although I tried `bg` with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure it is being run? It should show up in ps. What you have posted would not run the command in bash, you would need to have it inside inverted commas or `$()`.

Comment: that is a ruby example of how to run bash code.  pid = ... all that is in a rake task in ruby.  But yes, even pasting the code into shell inside those inverted quotes works and finds the rake task and pid.

Comment: Inside the inverted commas yes, I am saying that this `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake qc:work &` won't launch the code, it will just set the variable.